# R:How to give a correct values to the parameters of a Gaussian membership function

Tags: r, gaussian, membership

For applying any membership function, we need to assign values to its parameters.
 I want to apply Gaussian membership function  from FuzzyToolkitUoN  package to  a sample of weather dataset  using   as below:

```
T               H      P
307.59          50  1009
307.59          51  1008
307.3915127     51  984
275.1451997     52  984
306.8988867     54  1006
306.6525737     55  984
306.4062606     56  998
313.1599476     57  984
305.9136346     58  984
278.6673215     59  1035
325.4210085     60  1015
```

where:

```
T= temperature
P= Pressure
H= humidity
```

if  I want to apply Gaussian membership function to the temperature (T) as below:

```
TGaussian <<- gaussMF("cold", x, c(sigma, center, 1))
```

when I applied on T= temperature like :

```
x= 307.59 
sigma=1.5
center= 200
TGaussian <<- gaussMF("cold", x, c(sigma, center, 1))

>   TGaussian
$mfName
[1] "cold"

$mfType
[1] "gaussmf"

$mfX
[1] 307.59

$mfParams
[1]   1.5 200.0   1.0

$mfVals
[1] 0
```

I know `center=200` in not correct value, also `sigma=1.5`

**How can I  give both parameters (sigma, center)  correct values in this case?**

Comment: Always give details about additional R libraries you are using. `gaussMF` is not a base R function. [It seems](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/FuzzyToolkitUoN/versions/1.0/topics/gaussMF) the parameters are stored in `TGaussian$mfParams`.

Comment: I am using  (FuzzyToolkitUoN )Package, I want to convert  crisp data into Fuzzy data using Gaussian membership function

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49472943/edit) your post to include critical details. Also for future posts, learn how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including sample data. As I said in my previous comment, parameters are stored in `TGaussian$mfParams`. See `?gaussMF` for details!

Comment: Sorry. my question was not clear